# Error in adding multiple Foreign Keys in SQLite Database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

So I have multiple tables in my database. I have an **Employee** table that that has 2 foreign keys with the ID's from **Owner** and **Account** tables but I got an error following the code below:

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EMPLOYEE = " CREATE TABLE "
        + EMPLOYEE + "("
        + COL_EMP_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COL_EMP_LNAME + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_FNAME + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_IMG + "INTEGER,"
        + COL_EMP_DOB + "DATE,"
        + COL_EMP_GENDER + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_PHONE + "INTEGER,"
        + FOREIGN KEY("+ COL_OWNER_ID +") REFERENCES "+ OWNER +"("+ COL_OWNER_ID +"), "
        + FOREIGN KEY("+ COL_ACCT_ID +") REFERENCES "+ ACCOUNT +"("+ COL_ACCT_ID +"));";
```

I have also tried this one in adding multiple foreign keys but it also got me an error:

```
   ....
   + COL_OWNER_ID + "INTEGER REFERENCES" + OWNER +
   + COL_ACCT_ID + "INTEGER REFERENCES" + ACCOUNT+ ")";
```

Can you please tell me what's wrong with this code? Thanks

> Error: error: ';' expected     error: invalid method declaration; return
>   type required  error: illegal start of type    error: ';' expected
>   error: unclosed string literal     error: unclosed string literal  error:
>    expected

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: I'll update my OP

Comment: seems like syntax error in query. Print your query in log and check for proper spaces,single and double quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a syntax error in the java source, add a few `"` :

```
private static final String CREATE_TABLE_EMPLOYEE = " CREATE TABLE "
        + EMPLOYEE + "("
        + COL_EMP_ID + "INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"
        + COL_EMP_LNAME + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_FNAME + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_IMG + "INTEGER,"
        + COL_EMP_DOB + "DATE,"
        + COL_EMP_GENDER + "TEXT,"
        + COL_EMP_PHONE + "INTEGER,"
        + "FOREIGN KEY("+ COL_OWNER_ID +") REFERENCES "+ OWNER +"("+ COL_OWNER_ID +"), "
        + "FOREIGN KEY("+ COL_ACCT_ID +") REFERENCES "+ ACCOUNT +"("+ COL_ACCT_ID +"));";
```